# How to get Apple Music link with automation on macOS?

Tags: macos, automation

I need a way to get an Apple Music link to the currently playing song in the Music app on macOS.

Any method of automation is fine (AppleScript, Shortcuts, Keyboard Maestro, BetterTouchTool, etc).

Answer (score 2):

Here’s a quick shortcut I made to search the store for media matching the currently playing song and return its URL.

https://www.icloud.com/shortcuts/fb852634419a436c8c916717c6c800d9

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Dougscripts has some starter info on using AppleScript with Music and iTunes (for the older machines).

https://dougscripts.com/itunes/infocont.php

There's also the simplest way, the `Get the Current Song` action in Automator...

Comment: Apologies. I missed the explicit ref to Apple Music, the 'service'. My answer should still be ok in the context of returning what's currently playing. grg's answer is more correct re the store. I blame it on the fact I don't use Apple Music (the service)!